# Google sheets - move entered data based on a filter function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I think I know the answer to this, and it's no, but I thought I'd give it a whirl.

I have a spreadsheet that is populated -- based on user requests -- with a pair of FILTER functions, as follows:

In cell **H6:**
`=iferror(filter('Imported primary list'!A6:C,'Imported primary list'!D6:D="LastName"),"None")`

...and in cell **K6:**
`=iferror(filter('Imported primary list'!E6:E,'Imported primary list'!D6:D="LastName"),"None")`

Where *LastName* is the name of the person who generated the request, from another tab. This is going into columns **H, I, & J** on the filtered page (and column K with the second filter). Then, the user enters time info in column **L**.

**The problem:**

Because the filter function is pulling from an alphabetical list, every time the user selects another row to include, it resorts the list to include the new row, alphabetically. However, the timestamp entered by the user in Column **L** remains static. Thus, the rows are now misaligned.

The obvious solution is to tell users not to enter times until they're sure that there aren't new requests to make. However, that's not always feasible. I also can't have the users enter everything on the *Imported primary list* tab.

So, is there a way to move the text in column **L** to keep it with the filtered data from columns H-K? I think it would have to be a script, not a function, but I don't want something that would add too much processing. I think the answer is no, and users will just have to manually adjust their data, but I promised the user I'd ask.

Comment: If you can figure out the rules which of the cells to which of the rows should be aligned it can be done with a script. It could be a command 'Tidy up!' in the custom menu, for example.

Comment: I would agree with you that the answer is **`No`** & @YuriKhristich's comment as I also think that it would be better for this to be implemented using a script.